# I try to deploy my smart contract in truffle but is says "unsupported compiler" when I "truffle migrate" how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, deployment, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle

## PS D:\Projects\ANIS\Decentralized_Bank> truffle compile

## Compiling your contracts...

> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Tether.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Tether.sol
> Artifacts written to D:\Projects\ANIS\Decentralized_Bank\src\truffle_abis
> Compiled successfully using:

- solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

## PS D:\Projects\ANIS\Decentralized_Bank> [truffle migrate]

Compiling your contracts...

## Error: Unsupported compiler: [object Object]

```
at C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\index.js:28:1
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at compile (C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\index.js:26:1)
at Object.compile (C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\index.js:68:47)
at Object.compileAndSave (C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\index.js:95:47)
at Object.run (C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:199:1)
at Command.run (C:\Users\OMEN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:183:1)
```

Truffle v5.4.11 (core: 5.4.11)
Node v14.17.2

Answer (score 8):

## My mistake this error happens because I mistakenly typed "compiler" instead "compilers" in truffle-config.js file

## Correct code

compilers:{
solc:{
version: '^0.5.0',
optimizer:{
enabled: true,
runs: 200
}
}
}